# Get the average time of a column using TimeDiff

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, average

I am trying to compute the average time of process in a service named "ADD CERT"

Some Context:

- DateTimeEntered = Time when people started queuing
- DateTImeEnded = Time when people ended their queue.

```sql
SELECT AVG(TIMEDIFF(DateTimeEnded, DateTimeEntered))AS AverageTime
FROM tblqueuenumber
WHERE Service = 'ADD CERT'
```

Comment: And what is the issue with your query?  What is your question?

Comment: you are missing a `GROUP BY Service` ??

Comment: the format was not in time format

Comment: @MekanFLores please edit your question to add some sample data showing how does your `DateTimeEnded` and `DateTimeEntered` field looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your format is    HH:MM:SS so i think you need below

```
  select SEC_TO_TIME(avg(TIME_TO_SEC(DateTimeEnded)-TIME_TO_SEC(DateTimeEntered)))
   FROM tblqueuenumber
    WHERE Service = 'ADD CERT'
```